Сравнительный оборот или придаточное предложение с союзной конструкцией "скорей..., чем"?
"В женском характере есть такая черта, что если женщина в чем виновата, то скорей она согласится потом загладить свою вину тысячью ласк, чем в настоящую минуту, во время самой очевидной улики в проступке, сознаться в нем и попросить прощения"
В Интернете представлена разная информация, где-то сравнительная степень наречия + союз "чем" выделяется как особенность употребления придаточного сравнительного, а где-то предложения с "чем" являются сравнительным оборотом. Чем будет являться предложение, начинающееся с союза "чем", в данном случае?

В женском характере есть такая черта, что если женщина в чем виновата, то скорей она согласится потом загладить свою вину тысячью ласк, чем в настоящую минуту, во время самой очевидной улики в проступке, сознаться в нем и попросить прощения.

Предикативная основа: она согласится скорее загладить (вину), чем сознаться и попросить (прощения).

Здесь двойной союз скорее...чем, он используется для выражения сопоставительных значений. В этом предложении союз соединяет  инфинитивные части составного глагольного сказуемого.

В сложных предложениях используется сопоставительный союз чем...тем, например:

Чем дальше дорога уходила на Север, тем становилось холоднее.
Справочник
СКОРЕЕ... НЕЖЕЛИ / ЧЕМ, союз
 Запятая ставится перед второй частью союза («нежели» / 
 «чем»).
 Эта ее привычка задавать зря вопросы о предметах, не раз в 
 ее присутствии обсуждавшихся, была следствием скорее 
 нервности мысли, чем невнимания. В. Набоков, Камера 
 обскура. В ее семье мужчины скорее знали об учтивых 
 манерах, нежели владели ими. И. Бродский, Полторы комнаты.


Сложное предложение относится к СПП с придаточными сопоставительными, при этом для обозначения сопоставительных отношений дополнительно к двойному союзу  чем...тем используется сравнительная степень прилагательных или наречий.
